# I want to make a matrix(6,6) but it shows me other values (serves for newtonian interpolation)

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

First, I calculated the lower triangle and the main diagonal values with the formula: `f(i,j)=(f(i,j-1))-(f(i-1,j-1))/(x(i)- x(i-j)`, I made the matrix(6,6) so i can have the main diagonal from it, which values are defined with `b` in the code and shown as "Cosntante" in the promt.

Then i did the interpolation defined as `p` in the code and shown as " El valor aproximado de f() es:" in the promt.

```
program p4
use ISO_C_Binding
implicit none
real :: x(6), y(6), b(6), xi, p
integer :: i, j, n, m, k
real, dimension(6,6) :: f=c_float

f=0
x=[1.6, 2.0, 2.5, 3.2, 4.0, 4.5]
y=[2, 8, 14, 15, 8, 2]

n=SIZE(x)

do i=1,n
  f(i,1)=y(i)
end do

do i=1,n
   f(i,2:n)=0
end do

do j=2,n
   do i=j,n
      f(i,j)=(f(i,j-1))-(f(i-1,j-1))/(x(i)- x(i-j))
   end do
end do

do i=1,n
   write(*,*) F(i,:)
end do

do i=1,n
   b(i)=f(i,i)
   write(*,*) "Constante b[",i,"]=",b(i)
end do

xi=2.8
m=size(x)-1
p=b(m)

do k=2,m+1
   p=(b(m-k))+(xi-((x(m-k))*p))
end do

write(*,*) "El valor aproximado de f(",xi,") es:",p
pause
end program p4
```

it shows me the next values (these are the values i get in ForceFortran):
[image]

And it should show me (these are the values i get in Python):

[image]
[image]

What should i do?

Comment: Compile with -fcheck=all and run it again - what does that tell you?

Comment: @ianBush is right. Fortran default origin index is 1. But in your code, if you check your 3rd do-loop (which is the double do-loop "do j = 2,n" "do i = j,n" when i = j, there is "x(i-j)" which is a "x(0)" --> out of bounds of your array. This could be a first origin of your problem